# Cant check out 2gb repo

Tags: github, bitbucket

I am trying to clone a big repo from bitbucket.org but im facing the following error its near 2gb in size so it is when I try to clone the repo i get the following error message which I have not got before.

> warning: templates not found C:\Program
>   Files\Git\share\git-core\templates
>
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>
> error: RPC failed; curl 52 Empty reply from server
>
> Completed with errors, see above.

Does anybody no how to solve this I have not much expierence with the git command line just the sourcetree user interface any help is greatly apreciated, would I be better copying the files locally on pc and just push them to a new repo im wanting to simply clone the project for a new version of the product.

Regards and many thanks,
Treat others as to how you wish to treat others.

If this is the wrong stackexchange to post this please forgive me

Comment: Curious, but which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Sorry what difference does that make when i can check out other repos fine source tree works without issues on others but WIndows Ten

Comment: Can you try to clone it with your system Git version (i.e. `git clone git@bitbucket.org:username/repo-slug.git` on the command line)? Also it might be worth trying to switch SourceTree to use the system version of Git.

Comment: There was a Windows 10 update released on October 27; since then, we've had reports of this exact message from a number of Windows 10 users, but not from users of any other operating system (even other versions of Windows).